# Html.Hidden value lost from View to Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to add a value coming from an ajax result to other parameters the form is already passing to the controller.
Apart from this parameter form and controller work exactly as expected.

This is the controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Search(int? page, int? selectedCategoryID, int[] geoDataID = null, string searchString = "", string sortBy = "")
```

The Parameter causing problems is 'int[]geoDataID'.
In order to pass it from ajax.result to the controller an hidden field is being used. Moreover, as this value must be subsequently passed to another view I am using the ViewBag to pass its value back from the controller.
Here's the form: Html.Action and the input are been used to fill other DDL and pass the others params to the controller. All the them are working just fine.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left" }))
            {
                @Html.Action("GetCategoryList", "Categories")
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="searchString" name="searchString" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search string" onfocus="this.value=''" />
                </div>
                @Html.Action("GetRangeIput", "GeoData")
                @Html.Hidden("geoDataID", (object)ViewBag.geoDataID, new { id = "geoDataID" })
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            }
```

The ajax result is passed (that would be the idea) to the

```
@Html.Hidden("geoDataID", (object)ViewBag.geoDataID, new { id = "geoDataID" })
```

The jquery.ajax also is nothing special

```
$('#selectedRangeID').change(function () {
            var rangeSelected = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("getGeoDataInRangeID", "Manage")',
                datatype: "json",
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    range: rangeSelected * 5000,
                    latitude: LATITUDE,
                    longitude: LONGITUDE
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#geoDataID').val(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve range geodata.');
                }
            });
        })
```

and`it works as expected: when I alert the result I can see the data value and when I look at the produced html output the hidden field has been filled with data.
from

```
<input id="geoDataID" name="geoDataID" type="hidden" value="" />
```

to, as an example

```
<input class="input-validation-error" id="geoDataID" name="geoDataID" type="hidden" value="3440,3442,3444,3446,3447,3448,3449,3450,3451,3452,3453,3454,3455,3456,3457,3458,3468,3469,3470,3473,3475,3476,3477,3478,3479,3480,3481,3482,3483,3484,3485,3486,3487,3488,3577,3579,3592,3593,3610,3616,3617" />
```

As a matter of fact all but this parameter get to the controller as the form is submitted, and I cannot figure out what's missing.

Comment: is geoDataId an integer array? try using string instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is probably because your function is expecting an int array and gets a comma separated string instead.

try using

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Search(int? page, int? selectedCategoryID, string geoDataID = null, string searchString = "", string sortBy = "")
```

and then convert the comma separated string into an string array like this:

`var strGeoDataId = geoDataID.split(',');`

and then int parse each of them to convert it to an integer array.

`var intGeoDataId = Array.ConvertAll(strGeoDataId, int.Parse);`

hope this helps!

Comment: You were right mate! Unfortunately it's not so straightforward to convert a comma separated string into an integer Array but I suppose it can be worked out. Thanks!

Comment: whats the issue? if you update the question, people would help you make it easy!

Comment: You cannot convert strings to an int[] without casting every item. Try it.

Comment: This solves the conversion issue: 
IEnumerable<int> GeoData = StringToIntList(geoDataID);
 public static IEnumerable<int> StringToIntList(string str)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                yield break;

            foreach (var s in str.Split(','))
            {
                int num;
                if (int.TryParse(s, out num))
                    yield return num;
            }
        }

Comment: i have just added a bit code for the convertsion to int array.
 In JS its as easy as it was earlier.(Got confused! :D)